# How to cast CV_64F type Matrix to 1D Array with Double elements

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, opencv3.0, mat

I couldn't find an answer to this question but I believe it should be easily done.

Here I have following data structures;

```
Mat MyMatrix = Mat(3, 1, CV_64F, &targetArray) //Some 3x1 data in it
// Some process...

array <double ,3> MyArray
MyMatrix.convertTo(MyArray, double, 0 , DBL_MAX)
```

I want to convert MyMatrix (which I guarantee to be 3x1) to an 1D Array (Array elements should be double). How can I do that with C++ and opencv3.0.1?

Comment: You could try `cv::reshape`. With that function you can change the amount of rows and channels of your matrix. However, I'm not sure hot to convert it to an array afterwards. `cv::Mat::ptr<T>(int)` gives you a ptr to the beginning of the specified row. However, I am not sure if the whole matrix is contiguous in memory. So I guess you'll have to copy one row after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a `cv::Mat` to a `std::array`. You can only *copy* the data into an array.

Given a

```
Mat m = Mat(3, 1, CV_64F);
// fill with some value
```

you can use `memcpy`:

```
array<double, 3> a; 
memcpy(a.data(), m.ptr<double>(0), 3*sizeof(double));
```

or `std::copy`:

```
array<double, 3> b;
copy(m.begin<double>(), m.end<double>(), b.begin());
```

or, since it's only 3 elements, the array constructor:

```
array<double, 3> c = {m.at<double>(0), m.at<double>(1), m.at<double>(2)};
```

or, obviously, with a loop:

```
array<double, 3> d;
for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i) { d[i] = m.at<double>(i); }
```

---

Conversion is instead possible with `std::vector`:

```
vector<double> e = m;
```

---

Note that, instead of a matrix with only 3 values, you can use `Vec3d`, or `Matx31` or `Matx13`. Using `Mat1d` would however simplify the notation and make the code less verbose.

Comment: I understand your solution but can you please elaborate why I cannot use following code or any conversion methodology?

    vector<double> e = m; //I tried and it did not worked

Comment: You **can** convert to a `vector<T>` because the `Mat` object has defined the [conversion to a vector](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L1489). It works, probably you messed up some code.

Comment: Sorry, I converted to  <vector>    but not  <array>   . Why can't I convert to arrays, I just want to know this part? Thanks.

Comment: because `Mat` doesn't define a conversion operator to `std::array`. That actually wouldn't  make much sense, since you can't know at compile time the size of the matrix. And if you know it because of some constraint, such as in this case, just use one of the formulation above. The question is  _why_ you need to use an array instead of a vector, or work on raw pointers